# Featherlight.js - closing and loading new content

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I am using featherlight (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) in my custom Wordpress theme to display posts from a custom category. I have posts which are linked like this:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Which open up fine. Then inside the featherlight popup, I want to have previous and next buttons so the user can scroll between posts. So far the next button is like this:

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="<?php echo $next; ?>">NEXT</a>
```

Which does open a new featherlight frame with the correct content, but doesn't close the current one. So after clicking through a bunch of times, you have to close all the frames you opened up!

I have been looking for some solutions for this but I'm not experienced enough with Jquery to get anything working. I was thinking this might be possible with the beforeOpen setting? Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Featherlight has [a gallery feature/plugin](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html) that you should be using!

Comment: I took a look at that, but I could only figure out how to use the next/previous buttons for links that were side by side like:

    <section data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
    <a href="photo_large.jpg"><img src="photo_thumbnail.jpg"></a>
    <a href="other_photo_large.jpg"><img src="other_photo_thumbnail.jpg></a>
    </section>

With wordpress I can't format links to the posts like that as they are in different places of the html code. Is there another way to do it?